# Accessing company data from Salesforce

Tags: python, python-2.7, salesforce

I would like to retrieve company information from salesforece crm. I tried it using beatbox package. The code is

```
import beatbox

sf_username = "myusername"
sf_password = "mypassword"
sf_api_token = "mytoken"

def get_lead_records_by_email():
    sf_client = beatbox.PythonClient()
    password = str("%s%s" % (mypassword, mytoken))
    sf_client.login(sf_username, password)
    lead_qry = "SELECT City,State,Street,NumberOfEmployees,CompanyId FROM DatacloudCompany WHERE DunsNumber = '008528283'"
    records = sf_client.query(lead_qry)
    return records

print get_lead_records_by_email()
```

But I am getting the following error:

`beatbox._beatbox.SoapFaultError: 'INVALID_TYPE' "INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'DatacloudCompany' is not supported."`

Is there anything that i am doing wrong?

I saw a couple of other packages like simple salesforce and pyforce. Will beatbox be the best one to use or should I opt for some other package?

Any help in the right direction will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked whether there is any pricing for getting information?

Answer (score 0):

"INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'DatacloudCompany' is not supported."

try using another library that maybe supports  DatacloudCompany such as simples-salesforce or RestForce